# Mongodump from remote mongo server

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, mongodb-query, nosql

I'm trying to dump the mongo database using the command, from my private MongoDB server, I can connect to the mongo server via mongo shell and do all the operations but mongodump isn't working for some reason, I'm getting this error.

```
2020-07-31T22:03:13.976+0000    writing mydb.movie to archive 'mydb.archive'
2020-07-31T22:03:13.980+0000    Failed: error writing data for collection `mydb.movie` to disk: error reading collection: Failed to parse: { find: "movie", skip: 0, snapshot: true, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "mydb" }. Unrecognized field 'snapshot'.
```

the Command I'm using

```
mongodump --host 10.0.1.33:27017 --db mydb --username myusername --password mypassword --authenticationDatabase admin --gzip --archive=mydb.archive
```

Note: this command run perfectly fine when I login to the mongo server itself via ssh, and execute the above dump command.

Thank you

Comment: Can you connect to mongodb via shell?

Comment: You have a mismatch in server version vs mongodump you are using remotely? Install same version of tools as your server.

Comment: @Yahya yes I can connect via shell from my remote server.

Comment: @D.SM I've installed them together on both servers, in the remote server, I just have mongo shell, on the mongo server, I've complete mongo (shell and demon)

Comment: Run mongo --version, mongod --version and mongodump --version on both systems.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-112:~$ mongodump --version
mongodump version: built-without-version-string
git version: built-without-git-spec
Go version: go1.10.1
   os: linux
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017

------------------------------------------
Second server
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-33 ~]$ mongodump --version
mongodump version: r4.0.19
git version: 7e28f4296a04d858a2e3dd84a1e79c9ba59a9568
Go version: go1.11.13
   os: linux
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010